# Why is this static property coming up undefined? How to access static properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a 'class' called FileController in which I store a static property. For what its worth its a string I use to identify an event type. When I try to access the string as static property of the 'class' its coming up undefined. I am wondering why?

```
FileController = function(galId)
{

FileController.GALLERY_UPLOAD_START = "galleryUploadStart";
}
```

//then in another file...

```
function initDragSystem()
{
console.log('@initDragSystem FileController ' + FileController); //Traces out the constructor method
console.log('@initDragSystem FileController.GALLERY_UPLOAD_START = ' +     FileController.GALLERY_UPLOAD_START) //traces out 'undefined'

}
```

Comment: Move the property initialization line outside of the function, so you don't have to call it in order for it to be defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call or invoke the function first, after it is invoked then the property is set:-

```
FileController(123);

console.log(FileController.GALLERY_UPLOAD_START);//Now this will work.
```

Or

```
FileController = function(galId)
{


}

FileController.GALLERY_UPLOAD_START = "galleryUploadStart";
```

Comment: Alternately, move the line setting the "static" variable to outside the constructor.

Comment: Yes, move the static variable outside of the function, if you want to access without invoking it.

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway to access the property like a static property of the class without calling the function, similar to something like Math.pi?

Comment: @ScottWright code updated. You can use the static property now without invoking the function.

Comment: Much appreciated - that works the way I want it to. Thx guys.